# Friend function defined inside class not seen by compiler

Tags: c++

While compiling the following code:

```
class A {
    A() = default;
public:
    friend A getA() {
        return A();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a = getA();
}
```

The compiler gives me an error:

> 'getA' was not declared in this scope

Why is that?

Comment: While `getA` is  not a member function, it's still declared in the scope of the `A` class. Declaring friend function without a declaration to put it in the outer namespace scope is useful when it can be used for [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (which is common for example the output and input operator `<<` and `>>`). But in this case there's simply no `::getA` function.

Comment: Why can't I call function getA() in a member function of a class A? If I try to do so compiler says still 'getA' was not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [friend function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Notes) `getA` can't be found by name lookup.

(emphasis mine)

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within class or class
>   template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X,
>   but **is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that
>   considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is
>   provided**

`getA` can't be found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) either, (it has no parameters). You need to provide a declaration at the namespace scope. e.g.

```
class A;
A getA();
class A {
    A() = default;
public:
    friend A getA() {
        return A();
    }
};
```