# Getting undefined reference to a properly defined friend function -_-

Tags: c++, class, undefined-reference, friend-function

So... I was happily working on a project and then I was going to implement a friend function, which returns an object of the class after generating a random number of arbitrary size. On compilation, it's showing the error undefined reference... blah blah blah

Below is a brief mimic of the actual code/issue...

class Declaration: Random.h

```
// Random Declarations

#ifndef _RANDOM_H
    #define _RANDOM_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>


using uv = std::vector<uint16_t>;
using std::ostream;
using std::size_t;

class Random {
    uv data;

public:

    friend Random generate(const size_t&);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Random&);
};

#endif
```

class Definition: Random.cpp

```
// Random Definitions

#include "Random.h"
#include <cstdlib>

Random generate(const size_t& sz) {
    Random newRandom;
    newRandom.data.resize(sz);
    for(auto &x : newRandom.data) {
        x = rand();
    }
    return newRandom;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Random& random) {
    if(random.data.empty()) {
        out << '0';
    } else {
        for(auto &x : random.data) {
            out << x;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

And here is the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Random.h"

int main() {
    Random r = generate(10U); // <-- This line is throwing the error
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Error:

```
PS D:\INT\The Friend Issue> g++ main.cpp Random.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:28: error: 'generate' was not declared in this scope
     Random r = generate(10U);
                        ^
```

By the way, if I declare the generate in main also then it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Random.h"

Random generate(const std::size_t&);

int main() {
    Random r = generate(10U);
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

No Error

```
PS D:\INT\The Friend Issue> g++ main.cpp Random.cpp
PS D:\INT\The Friend Issue> .\a.exe
4118467633426500191691572411478293582696224464
```

Any help would be thankful...

Comment: `#define _RANDOM_H` That name is reserved for the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should use another header guard.

Comment: Instead of using the **C** header file `#include <stdint.h>`, try using the **C++** header file `#include <cstdint>`.

Comment: *"blah blah blah"* -- Do you really care this little about your question?

Comment: *By the way, if I declare the generate in main also then it works.*  If you'd declare it in the header file, it'd also work.  As is now, the function is a *hidden friend*, and inaccessible through ADL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Friend function defined inside class not seen by compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360176/friend-function-defined-inside-class-not-seen-by-compiler) *Note how simple the [mre] is in that question. There is only one file, hence no header guards to serve as distractions.*

Comment: As in the suggested duplicate, you'll need a `Random generate(const std::size_t&);` line (as you eventually added in your main.cpp) in the Random.h header. That will declare the free-standing (global) function that you eventually define in Random.cpp.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes I got it now... it was a silly mistake, due to lack of my knowledge of friend functions... Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in Random.cpp tells it that generate is a function of Random.  Use the notation

```
Random Random::generate(const size_t& sz) {
...
```

otherwise its just another global function.
Also the public seems to indicate you want it exposed so there should be no reason for friendship.  In Random.h you likely meant

```
static Random generate(const size_t&);
```

Finally nothing in main tells it that generate is a static function of Random so in main.cpp

```
Random r = Random::generate(10U);
```

If it were not static, you would need a Random to call it on.  More likely you really wanted a constructor rather than generate, but that's more an organizational choice.

Comment: OP doesn't *want* `generate` to be a member function; it is a ***friend*** of the class.

Comment: with generate as a global function, a friend, and doing the job of a constructor, I'll let the OP clarify wants...